# Do the Infinity Gems spell out Thanos?

Tags: analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe

A common theory surrounding the Infinity Stones is, that the first letter of the form they are found in combines to spell out the name Thanos. The images below show the theory in action, including a guess at where we might eventually see the Soul Gem (the only Infinity Stone not yet found as of *Doctor Strange*).

[image]

[image]

Is there any truth in this fan speculation, or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: See: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87643/is-infinity-stones-making-the-name-of-thanos-true

Comment: @KutuluMike Didn't noticed it while positing and not even a regular there. Anyways someone might come up with a better answer here.

Comment: Nah, you can easily make stuff like that up. Like, who possessed each stone at some point? Reality: **M**alekith, Time: **A**gamotto, Power: **R**onan, Mind: **V**ision, Soul: ????? [**E**veryone?], Space: **L**oki. :P

Comment: @Walt Lol, nice one :D

Comment: Looking at the colours, I see: Space: **C**yan. Mind: **Y**ellow. Power: **B**lue. Soul: **O**range. Reality: **R**ed. Time: **G**reen. So clearly this hints at a CYBORG!

Comment: @Walt that's especially true when three of your letters are T, N, S -- the most commonly-used letters in the English language. Ask anyone who's seen _Wheel of Fortune_

Comment: @KutuluMike A and E are also at the top

Comment: "Necklace". This picture is already streching pretty far to make this fit

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**No**, that's absolutely not true.

Even before *Doctor Strange* came out, this was unlikely to be true. See, for example, Thaddeus's excellent response to [the same question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87643/is-infinity-stones-making-the-name-of-thanos-true) on our sister site (with a lot of information pulled from the comics source material).

The big problem with the theory is that it requires you to start by assuming it's true, then work backward to pick names that fit. It's already on sketchy ground with the unnamed staff Loki has (why is that 's' and not 'l'? Because there's no 'l' in THANOS), and the orb from *Guardians of the Galaxy*. People then took this a step further to try and "guess" what 'n' and 'h' would be, and it got kinda silly.

But we now *know* where the Time Gem is. It's in the Eye of Agamatto. There is no 'e' in THANOS, and the 'a' is already covered by the Aether. There's no reasonable way to fit the Eye of Agamotto into this theory.

It was just a coincidence.

Comment: To fit the theory  Eye of Agamattois counted  as neckless and soul gem is speculated to be related to Heimdall as shown in images .

Comment: @AnkitSharma The fact that the Eye of Agamotto has to be renamed to "necklace" for this theory to work while the Tesseract is still called the Tesseract instead of just "cube" is evidence enough that this theory simply doesn't work. It's just as KutuluMike said - a theory that the evidence is being forced to fit, rather than a theory that the evidence naturally supports.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Typically "necklace" is used when the "chain" is a significant part of the piece; when the main point is the single central piece, it's generally referred to as a "pendant". When that central piece is considered magical, it's almost exclusively called an "amulet". So calling the Eye of Agamotto a "necklace" just to make it fit this name scheme is a pretty big stretch.

Answer (score 5):

With the release of *Infinity War*, we can now definitively conclude that the theory was **false**.

The Soul Stone was

> on the planet Vormir. It wasn't inside any artifact, nor was it associated with anything beginning with the letter "H".

So even if, at a stretch, you can say the N stands for Necklace, there is no reasonable way to make the Soul Stone fit the letter H. So it really was just coincidence.

Comment: Ha! The stone was on planet vormir, yes, but it was hidden behind a test of _**H**eart_! One in which Thanos was forced to kill that **H**ot green chick. Oh, and to close it all - the keeper was **H**ed Skull! /sarcasm

Comment: **Please stop suggesting edits that try to justify what the H might stand for.** That's the third one I've had to reject. If you disagree with my answer, post your own instead of vandalising mine. Thank you.